# Save text to Exisit file c#

Tags: c#, winforms, save

I'am trying to add new text to exist file which i created but when he click save i have always the same save us. Program adding text but i always must create new text.

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");

using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
{
      if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {          
          text = "iNFO ADD" + " = " + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine;
          File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, text);
      }
}
```

Comment: If you want to overwrite the previous content of the file use File.WriteAllText instead of AppendAllText

Comment: Looks like all you really want is `File.AppendText(...);`  Not sure why you are using a SaveDialog if you already know the file name.

Comment: You are "appending" text to an empty file, unless `saveFileDialog1.FileName` is `@"D:\test.txt"`. You likely want to change `text =` to `text +=`, to firstly append text to the string, *then* you can append that string to a file (or just File.WriteAllText if you intend to be creating a new file).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your text in string[] or List and after that add in text file.

```
using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        List<string> appendLines = new List<string>()
        {
            "one string",
            "two string"
        };

        File.AppendAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, appendLines);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `text =` to `text +=`, and also use `WriteAllText` in case the file is the same as the one you just read in (otherwise you will read in the file, then append the same data back into the file). Currently you are reading a file into the variable `text`, the immediately overwriting all of that data with new data.

```
   string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");    

   using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
       if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           text += "iNFO ADD" + " = " + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine;
           File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, text);
       }
```

Or, if you really want to use `AppendAllText` and simply want to append to an existing file, you actually want to leave your `text =` unchanged and do this instead (no reason to read in the file):

```
   string fileName = @"D:\test.txt"; 

   using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
       if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           string text = "iNFO ADD" + " = " + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine;
           File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
       }
```